# Slow resume from s2disk

Tags: partitioning, kernel, suspend

when I resume after suspending with s2disk the machine is often very slow for a few minutes. I think this has to do with my swap partition being too small. Here is a screenshot of what gparted shows: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr9K8.png)

The log in /var/log/kern.log shows

```
Dec  3 09:53:54 Thinkpad-e440 kernel: [19625.099947] PM: Preallocating image memory... done (allocated 513712 pages)
Dec  3 09:53:55 Thinkpad-e440 kernel: [19651.121557] PM: Allocated 2054848 kbytes in 26.00 seconds (79.03 MB/s)
```

This seems to be the bottle neck. After several minutes the machine is just as fast as it always is.